# code for putting the clicked element at the first position in a list of elements using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a list of un ordered  items.In that list of items the clicked element should come to the first position in the order and the remaining elements which are prior the clicked element should come to the last position in the list.

for example:
I have a list of elements like this in order

Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 Item5 Item6 Item7 Item8

suppose if i clicked the link "Item4" then Item4 should be in the position of Item1 and the items which are prior to Item4 should come next to the Item8 means like below

Item4 Item5 Item6 Item7 Item8 Item1 Item2 Item3

### Please look into this requirement:--

**I have one more requirement like here i hav list like this when elements list increases the elements are coming to the next line . so i want to keep two arrows at the both the ends of the list.On clicking of those arrows either left side arrow or right side error the list should move according to the arrow direction**

**For Example:**
**Before clicking**

<< Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 Item5 Item6 Item7 Item8 Item9 **>>** Item10 Item11 Item12

**After clicking right side arrow:**

Item1 **<<** Item2 Item3 Item4 Item5 Item6 Item7 Item8 Item9 Item10 **>>** Item11 Item12

It should support this and above requirement.
**Please please help me in resolving this problem by using jquery carousel or by using any sliders**

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
$('li').click(function(){
   var lis =  $(this).nextAll().andSelf();
   $(this).parent().prepend(lis)
});
```

html

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/c4GNq/

Comment: thanks Nicola i have implemented your code ...please help me in solving the additional requirement also..

Answer (score 2):

[try this one](http://jsfiddle.net/nQsrN/1/):

```
$(function() {
    $('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
        //cache clicked element
        var clickedItem = $(this);

        //get next siblings and self, and append to first position
        clickedItem.nextAll().andSelf().prependTo(clickedItem.parent());
    });
});​
```

Comment: i dont get it. if you click on either arrow, the items on both sides go to the outside?

Comment: No joseph the functionality you can see in IE browser if you open more number of tabs then it shows arrows to navigate to overflowed tabs..

Comment: Iam new to this Jquery and javascript.I dont knw how to do this.You can have the picture how my requirement is at this link
https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=061D92931464B02E&id=61D92931464B02E%21122
thanks..